# How to set Total Pages in JQGrid if I'm using server side paging?

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I'm new to JQGrid and learning the paging currently. I'm trying to implement server side paging.

Consider I have 45 records. Since, Server side returns the requested records of a specified page based on page size(say 10), my pager changes to 1 immediately after clicking next button. I'm not able to move on to further pages since the total page is 1 now. Total page is automatically getting calculated based on the records present. So how to manage the total pages value in this case?

```
   $("#jqGridOutbox").jqGrid({
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'POST',
            colNames: ['Title', 'Submitted By', 'Assigned To', 'Submitted On', 'History', 'WorkFlow Name'],
            colModel: [
                   { name: 'TitleOut', index: 'Title', width: 173, sortable: true, search: true, formatter: ShowItemFormatterOutbox },
                   { name: 'CreatedByOut', index: 'CreatedBy', width: 173, sortable: true, searchoptions: {} },
                   { name: 'PendingOnOut', index: 'PendingOn', width: 173, sortable: true, searchoptions: {} },
                   { name: 'CreatedOnOut', index: 'CreatedOn', width: 173, sortable: true, searchoptions: {} },
                   { name: 'HistoryOut', index: 'History', width: 80, sortable: false, search: false, formatter: ViewHistoryFormatter },
                   { name: 'WorkFlowNameOut', index: 'WorkFlowName', width: 170, sortable: true, search: true }
            ],
            datatype: function (postData) { getDataOutBox(postData, OutMode, OutPageNumber); },
            ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
            loadonce: 'false',
            viewrecords: 'true',
            width: 987,
            viewsortcols: [true, 'vertical', true],
            height: 250,
            rowList: [2, 5, 10, 20, 30, 100],
            hidegrid: 'false',
            rowNum: 2,
            autowidth: true,
            gridview: true,
            shrinkToFit: false,
            showQuery: 'true',
            jsonReader: {
                root: "rows",
                page: "page",
                total: "total",
                records: "records",
                cell: "cell",
                id: "Title", 
                userdata: "userdata",
                repeatitems: true
            },
            gridComplete: function () {
                $("#load_jqGridOutbox").hide();
                $("tr.jqgrow:odd").css("background", "white");
                $("tr.jqgrow:even").css("background", "#f7f7f7");
            },
            pager: '#jqGridOutboxPager',
            pagerpos: 'center'
        });
```

The function mapped to datatype is GetDataOutBox()

```
    function getDataOutBox(pdata, mode, pageNumber) {
        var params = new Object();
        params.page = pdata.page;
        params.pageSize = pdata.rows;
        params.sortIndex = pdata.sidx;
        params.sortDirection = pdata.sord;

        params.Title = $("#gs_TitleOut").val() == undefined ? '' : $("#gs_TitleOut").val();
        params.CreatedBy = $("#gs_CreatedByOut").val() == undefined ? '' : $("#gs_CreatedByOut").val();
        params.PendingOn = $("#gs_PendingOnOut").val() == undefined ? '' : $("#gs_PendingOnOut").val();
        params.CreatedOn = $("#gs_CreatedOnOut").val() == undefined ? '' : $("#gs_CreatedOnOut").val();
        params.WorkFlowName = $("#gs_WorkFlowNameOut").val() == undefined ? '' : $("#gs_WorkFlowNameOut").val();
        params.mode = mode;
        params.pageNumber = pageNumber;

        $("#load_jqGridOutbox").show();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ClaySysWorkFlowDashBoard.aspx/GetOutboxData',
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(params),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data, st) {
                if (st == "success") {
                    var grid = $("#jqGridOutbox")[0];
                    grid.addJSONData(data.d);
                    //$("#jqGridOutbox")[0].updatepager(false, true);
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("An error has occured retrieving the data!");
            }
        });
    }
```

The model which gets returned is

```
    public class JQGrid
    {
        public class Row
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public List<string> cell { get; set; }

            public Row()
            {
            cell = new List<string>();
            }
        }

        public int page { get; set; }
        public int total { get; set; }
        public int records { get; set; }
        public List<Row> rows { get; set; }

        public JQGrid()
        {
            rows = new List<Row>();
        }
    }
```

Based on the page number, I select only the respective set of 10 records. Thus after returning that, the total pages changes to 1.

Comment: Show your code . if possible,  what you have done till now

Comment: @AsifRaza added my code progress asif.

Comment: Make sure public int page { get; set; }
        public int total { get; set; }
        public int records { get; set; }
        public List<Row> rows { get; set; } have correct value.

Comment: according to what I guess, page holds the actual page number, total holds total count, records holds the current selected records count, and rows having the set of records.

In my example, consider page size 2. From page 1, if next is clicked, page value is 2, total is 8, and records is 2, rows is the 3 and 4th records.